# how can I merge sparse tables in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, merge, apache-pig

I have a number of csv files containing a single column of values:

File1:

```
ID|V1
1111|101
4444|101
```

File2:

```
ID|V2
2222|102
4444|102
```

File3:

```
ID|V3
3333|103
4444|103
```

I want to combine these to get:

```
ID|V1|V2|V3
1111|101||
2222||102|
3333|||103
4444|101|102|103
```

There are many (100 million) rows, and about 100 columns/tables.
I've been trying to use Pig, but I'm a beginner, and am struggling.

For two files, I can do:

```
s1 = load 'file1.psv' using PigStorage('|') as (ID,V1);
s2 = load 'file2.psv' using PigStorage('|') as (ID,V2);
cg = cogroup s1 by ID, s2 by ID
merged = foreach cg generate group, flatten((IsEmpty(s1) ? null : s1.V1)), flatten((IsEmpty(s2) ? null : s2.V2));
```

But I would like to do this with whatever files are present, up to 100 or so, and I don't think I can cogroup that many big files without running out of memory. So I'd rather get the column name from the header than just hard-coding it.  In other words, this 2-file toy example doesn't scale.

Comment: Why Pig?  Are you running in distributed mode?  I would think a full outer-join in Spark could work well provided a suitable distribution of the tasks were specified.  Joins are costly though, and I've never had such a large number of rows to work with.

Comment: the combined table will be loaded into HBase; the purpose of combining the separate tables is to reduce the number of HBase ingestions.  Hive might help here, but that's something else I'd need help with.